# In-app Review Link

Tags: iphone, url, app-store, review

I am trying to link directly from my app to the review page of an app.

This works perfectly with some of my App ID's, like this one [375031865]:

```
NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=375031865&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reviewURL]];
```

This also works (Same APP ID, different link format):

```
NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=375031865";
```

But does not work with other App ID's, like this one [392551011]:

```
NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=392551011&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reviewURL]];
```

OR:

```
NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=392551011";
```

I have no idea how the same exact link with a different APP ID in it will work for some apps but not others. The error that comes up is "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are they both published under "Purple Software?"  Maybe itunes doesn't like incorrect references?

Comment: @ObjectiveFlas: Were you able to solve your problem? Post your own answer. I am looking for this too.

Answer (score 1):

for 392551011 = The DumDumb Exam HD

try:

```
NSString *reviewURL =
 @"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/thedumdumbexamhd";
```

Entering the above URL into Safari on the device will take me to the App Store page. The URL string is the app name taken from the URL:

> http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-dumdumb-exam-hd/id392551011?mt=8

then converted into lower case and the spaces and the dashes removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully find out your app ID! Sometimes it differs for desktop and mobile iTunes.

I used iTunes (copy URL) way and stuck with "Cannot connect to iTunes". It returned irregular app id!

So for me the answer is to check app id in iTunesConnect or here: http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/