# Launching the App Store from an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

How can i launching the App Store from an iPhone application without launching Safari ?
i found something in  [Technical Q&A QA1629](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html) but doesn't work because i don't know how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:aURL];
```

And insert the url of the app in the iTunes App Store, instead of using http://, use itms://

Answer (score 0):

You could do as Timothy suggests.

Alternatively, if you want to take the user to the app store of the country where the user is registered look at: [In-app Review Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077146/in-app-review-link/4347150#4347150)